# Dependency Injection into Spring Servlet context (OncePerRequestFilter)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented a `OncePerRequestFilter`, where in the `doFilterInternal()` I would like to use an utilization class, that used `JdbcTemplate` and user data from a properties file. I realized that it couldn't reach the data from the properties file (database connection and variables) and has null value all the time. As I found on the internet it's, because of the different context.

I could successfully setup a new jdbc datasource locally, but I wouldn't like to duplicate the code, so I would like to inject simply the sources the same way as I did everywhere else like in RestControllers (`@Value`, `@Autowired`).

Any idea, how could I inject these in my utilization class that will be used in the servlet filter or directly in my filter?

Thank you!

UPDATE - code snippets:

In the `RestController`, the injection of `JdbcTemplate` works properly, but in the filter I cannot inject it, always throws `nullPointerException`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AsdApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AsdApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            DelegatingFilterProxy delegateFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
            delegateFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName("MyFilter");
            return new Filter[] { delegateFilterProxy };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class RestCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTest() {
        String result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<query>", String.class);
        System.out.println("result in ctrl: " + result);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("asd ad asd asd asd", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
@Component(value = "MyFilter")
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<query>", String.class);
        System.out.println("result in filter: " + result);

        User currentUser = new User("username", "password", new ArrayList<>());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticatedUser = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                currentUser, null, currentUser.getAuthorities()
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:<sqlserver>
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<pass>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: Make your filter spring managed and use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` to have the actual filter chain do the lookup. That way you can use `@Value` and `@Autowired`. Note when using Spring Boot this would all just work out-of-the-box.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I implemented `DelegatingFilterProxy` via extended `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` based on the following example from [Baeldung](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-core/src/main/java/com/baeldung/app/App.java), but I still get null, when I would like to use the `@Autowired` `jdbcTemplate` variable that setup in the properties file. The custom `OncePerRequestFilter` filter is marked as `@Component(<"filtername">). What did I wrong? Java 8+, Spring Boot 2.3.8

Comment: Then you haven't configured it correctly. An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if configured correctly. It would throw an exception at startup that the field could not be autowired and your application would simply fail to start.

Comment: Please add what you currently have (that isn't working) to your question as you keep lacking that information in your question.

Comment: You are doing `new MyFilter()` which will create an unmanaged instance. You are using Spring Boot (which was requested but neer answered). Just add an `@Bean` method that returns the filter, Spring Boot will register it for you, unless it really needs to be part of your security filter chain, then you need an additional `FilterRegistationBean`. Also what is the purpose of this filter?

Comment: @M.Deinum The purpose of my filter is simply check the JWT token of each request, then reject the request if it's not valid, else go further with the filtering chain. Based on your note, for this purpose I should use `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` instead of `OncePerRequestFilter`, because it's better with Spring Boot Security, right?

Comment: There is no such thing as Spring Boot Security, rather Spring Security. Also if there is a JWT token, why construct a default `UsernamePasswordToken` instead of retrieving those things (username etc.) from the token?

Comment: I get those data from the token, this code snippet is just a dummy example that demonstrate the logic for my filter usage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use this:

Through this class you can get different Spring Boot Beans in a non Bean class.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
            throws BeansException {
        ctx = appContext;

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Then after creating it, get your bean this way:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();

// Here you get your dependency
ARequiredClass dependency  = appCtx.getBean(ARequiredClass.class);
```

Comment: Although this works it is a workaround and rather a hack.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then what should be the proper way to solve this situation?

Comment: See the comment I gave on your question.

Comment: Before downvoting my answer try convincing me why this is not a good practice. @M.Deinum

Comment: Because this is the singleton (anti) pattern in desquise and will lead to surprising effects when used in an application with multiple `ApplicationContext`s in a hierarchy. Also there is no guarantee that when calling `getApplicationContext` that it has already been set. And finally operating on an `ApplicationContext` and doing a lookup should in general be avoided, as that generally indicates you are doing the wrong things (unless you are building a library/extension to Spring then it might! be a valid choice).

Answer (score 2):

As you are actually using Spring Boot and want to make it part of the Spring Security filter chain (which is something different!) what you need to do is

1. Create an `@Bean` method to create the filter and make it a bean
2. Create an `@Bean` method and add a `FilterRegistration` bean to prevent the bean from being registered as a filter by Spring Boot
3. Configure Spring Security.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(myFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}

@Bean
public MyFilter myFilter() {
  return new MyFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilterRegistationBean() {
  FilterRegistationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean(myFilter());
  frb.setEnabled(false);
  return frb;
}
```

Finally remove the `@Component` from your `MyFilter` as you don't need it and it would create an additional instance. All prior changes (like the `ApplicationInitializer` etc. you can remove.

**NOTE:** As you are using Spring Security and somehow use this for authentication, instead of extending `OncePerRequestFilter` I suggest you extend the Spring Security `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which integrates better with Spring Security (like fireing events for authentication, logging etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are creating a new instance of `MyFilter` instead of using the one managed by Spring with `@Component(value = "MyFilter")`

```
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Hence you will hit a NPE since `jdbcTemplate` is null. You can inject the instance managed be Spring instead of creating a new one.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyFilter")
    private MyFilter myFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(myFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, that was the issue! Thank you!